# ERROR: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been having this problem since yesterday and I have absolutely no idea how it happened. I've visited StackOverflow multiple times yet nothing seems to be helping.

Here's the error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

* Try:        
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or     --debug option
to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

This error made all my 'R' turn to red.

Comment: this problem is due to bad images in drawable folder

Comment: check your resources, have you added new drawable or layout before this error came?
this may be due to invalid name of drawable or invalid drawable, or you may have put things in wrong folder